# how do i put the any github code in my own panel

Tags: flutter, github, repository, github-api

I am working on a project that will create a relationship network of github projects with flutter. it will help these people understand complex projects. thanks to the github api, I need to copy and process the user's code. how can I do this?
the owner of the code will definitely be mentioned in the panel. i am grateful for every answer, I really need help.

Comment: What do mean by process the user's code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HimanshuArora I want to copy and use the code. this is what i need to access the class names inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access information from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ with [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)
and the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71705534/16593252)