# Copying source code using raw.githubusercontent.com

Tags: flutter, github

For example, I want to copy the user code in this link. I have to do this using flutter.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iampawan/FlutterExampleApps/master/main.dart

maybe i need to copy it to a txt file.
I don't know what to use. I searched but didn't understand enough. if there is any other option to copy the raw code i would like to know that too.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either the [HTTP Package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) or the [DIO Package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for this. I Recommend you using DIO.

You can send a GET Request to the URL you need, and it will return the content of the file you requested.

example with DIO:

```
Response response;
var dio = Dio();
response = await dio.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iampawan/FlutterExampleApps/master/main.dart');
print(response.data.toString());
```

for more info and usage please reffer to the posted plugins links.

Comment: That's work Srilal thanksss! In addition, those who need it can use it with FutureBuilder.